# Pairing Apple AirPods Pro as headset on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 20.04, microphone, headset

On my Lenovo ThinkPad P1 and Ubbuntu 20.04, after paring my Apple AirPods Pro, it is detected as Headhpones:
[Airpods Pro pairing details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArKMX.png)
Thus, no microphone is reported as an input for Sound settings:
[Sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYy5.png)
How can I change this and make use of my AirPods Pro microphone instead of internal one on laptop?

Comment: I've been having a similar problem with Bose wireless headphones- audio quality is only good when configured as an A2DP sink (not quite sure what this means), and the microphone never seems to work. It would be very interesting to know if anyone has found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can confirm that this issue also persists on Ubuntu 18.04. Further, it does not matter whether `etc/bluetooth/main.conf` has the setting `ControllerMode = bredr` or `ControllerMode = dual` as suggested by default almost every time this question comes up, both only lead to the airpods pairing as headphones, not as headsets.

Answer (score 0):

Microphone requires HSP/HFP profile, which doesn't seem to work well with PulseAudio but works fine with pipewire.

To confirm if it works for you in pipewire, try using it in Fedora 34+ live environment.